# Student voting system in Excel: Combination Slicer and Histogram

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-chart

I am trying to create an interactive chart with an Excel workbook (2016) to display the results of student voting. My workbook has several columns, but the two relevant here are "student name" and "score." Students submit a rating from 1-5 based on in-class activities, and we would like the results as a histogram which can be sorted by student name. In other words, we can see the histogram of all results, but I would then like to be able to filter for only one student's responses and have the histogram chart that subset of the data.

I have all of the data in a Pivot Table, and I have used a slicer to filter the table by student name. I have created a histogram in Data Analysis off that table, though it doesn't react to the slicer-- it only shows *all* the data, not any of the filtered subsets.

I'm not married to the Pivot Table and Slicer combination-- it's just the strategy I've tried thus far. Any suggestions? Much appreciated!

Comment: ...And I may have just answered my own question. I added the "student name" column to the Filters field in the Pivot Table. Not visually as nice as the Slicers option, but I think this is functional.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! It's a good idea to add your answer as an "answer," and then (if it doesn't get a better answer) to accept it, so that others can see there is a solution before opening it.